# Fiddler core, targetSession.fullUrl is not matching to the image url on the page

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, fiddler, fiddlercore

I am using Selenium webdriver, c# bindings and fiddler core. I am using fiddler core to get the response back from the image on the page of the application.

At the moment while I can output the targetSession.fullUrl for the url and the targetSession.status, for some reason its not matching for a logic test.

I'm out of ideas at the moment about why this is not working.

```
// Hook up the event for monitoring proxied traffic.
FiddlerApplication.AfterSessionComplete += delegate(Session targetSession)
{
    // Outputs the image url along with the other resources
    Console.WriteLine("Requested resource from URL {0} responseCode {1}",
    targetSession.fullUrl, targetSession.responseCode);

    // does output the one item with an response code that is not 200
   if (targetSession.responseCode != 200)
   {
    Console.WriteLine("Incorrect Status: {0}, {1}, {2} ", targetSession.fullUrl, 
    targetSession.responseCode, targetSession.RequestMethod);
   }

   // neither of these match the image url
   if (targetSession.fullUrl == targeturl && targetSession.responseCode == 200)
   {
    Console.WriteLine("Image is present: " + targetSession.fullUrl);
   }
   else if (targetSession.fullUrl == targeturl && targetSession.responseCode != 200)
   {
    Console.WriteLine("Image is not present: " + targetSession.fullUrl + 
    targetSession.responseCode);
   }
};
```

Comment: This is confusing - what are you trying to do? What does "not matching for a logic test" mean? What fails? What exceptions are thrown?

Comment: Sorry when I say logic test I mean the "==" above. These test is not behaving as I would expect (targetSession.fullUrl == targeturl). No exceptions given.

Comment: Put a breakpoint & logging in place. What's the value of `targetSession.fullUrl` vs `targeturl`?

Comment: I had already done this due to the comment below but thank you. It would have given the same solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are the expected and actual results? Did you maybe forget to enable HTTPS decryption? Did you check to see whether the URL on the page does a HTTP/3xx redirect to a different image?

Comment: Thanks I got an idea from this, the image url I am looking for had a caching id that changes for every webdriver session. Since its a string of numbers I didnt notice it was different and not part of the image identification. I just need to work out now how to remove that from the targeturl and the targetSession.fullUrl fiddler gives back.